# Java testing file LocalDate

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, int, localdate

Hello I have a Person class and a PersonTest.java to validate that my methods work properly, one of my methods determines and validates the persons age, however I get an error in my testclass that says     method getAge in class Person cannot be applied to given types;
  required: LocalDate
  found: no arguments

### reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Underneath is my method and the test method. Thank you in advance

```
public int getAge(LocalDate dob)
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        int age = Period.between(birthdate, today).getYears();
         if (age >= 14 && age <= 115) // valid employee dob
            this.birthdate = dob;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the Person must be between 14-               115");    

        return age;
    }
```

------------------------- Here is my testmethod ----------------------

```
 public void testGetAge(int age, LocalDate dob) {
        System.out.println("getAge");
        int expResult = 16;
        int result = validPerson.getAge(); // heres the error
        assertEquals(expResult, result);``
    }
```

Comment: you do not seem to be using the `dob` variable in `getAge` to check your validation - what is `birthdate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, the getAge method gets `LocalDate` input parameter, but in your test class you have called it without any parameter. That's why you get the error:

```
required: LocalDate found: no arguments
```

Just pass a parameter to it, or make it to use the `Person` age.

Comment: `int result = validPerson.getAge(dob);`

Comment: the testfile was given by our teacher, and for whatever reason the test class failed if it has parameters, and  
int result = validPerson.getAge(dob);    won't work unless I pass it into the method, as far as I know anyway. But thank you all for the help